# Precompile HTML pages in asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

I'd like to use Rails's asset pipeline to compile our custom HTTP error pages for nginx. I'd also like to use the standard Rails convention of a layout (say, `app/views/layouts/error.html.erb`) and views that render within that layout.

I found [one article describing a way to simply precompile some ERb templates](http://neovintage.blogspot.com/2012/02/precompile-static-html-pages-with-rails.html), but I'd still end up copying most of the layout code between the various templates.

I also thought about using `caches_page` in a controller and simply forcing the errors to occur during the build so that the files end up in `public`, but that seems really hacky.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up going the hacky route, which wasn't as hacky as I thought.

Basically, I created a controller, routes, and templates for the errors I plan to handle:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :errors, only: :show

# app/controllers/errors_controller.rb
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
  layout 'errors'

  # you may need to disable various filters
  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!

  # cache full versions of the pages we generate
  caches_page :show

  def show
    render action: params[:id]
  end
end

# app/views/errors/404.html.erb and so on
<p>404 Not Found</p>
```

Then I created a Rake task to "visit" each of these pages, which will cause the controller to cache the page in `/public/errors`:

```
task :create_error_pages => :environment do
  session = ActionDispatch::Integration::Session.new(Rails.application)

  %w{401 404 422 ...}.each do |error|
    session.get("/errors/#{error}")
  end
end
```

Now during deploy, I run this:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile create_error_pages
```

to generate our static HTTP error pages.

This will work in any environment where `config.action_controller.perform_caching = true`. This is on by default in production, but not in development, so be aware.

Comment: If you add `config.force_ssl = true ` to production.rb?  You'll need to change the get to be: `session.get("/errors/#{error}", {}, {'HTTPS' => 'on'} )`.